# get the value of the drop down in jquery on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the value of the dropdown on document ready but i am getting only the first value of the drop down
I have tried this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var car=$('.car').val();
        alert(car);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you really want to use a change Event. When the page loads the value will always be the default value (first value if not set).

Comment: @Ninad. I have modified my answer as per your request. Have a check at it and share thoughts.

Comment: @Ninad. I have made it as a working example and you can have a try and if you face any hindrance let me know

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var car = $('.car :selected').val();
        alert(car);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to given the `onchange=""` in the select tag so that when you change the select it will be fetching the value and then it will be alerting it.

Here is the sample that i have provided for you to understand.

```js
function myalert(a)
{
alert(a);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="myalert(this.value)">  
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

**Output:** - It will be alerting the value based on the chosen value from the select tag

Comment: I don't want only the selected value i want the values to be alerted when i select those value in the dropdown.

Comment: In your `select tag` you have not written `onchange()` property  or you have not use the `change()` in the script as well. That is the reson it is not working under document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could add attribute 'selected' to your desired option. Please consider html below.
P.S.: I've added attribute on 'Mercedes'.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var car=$('.car').val();
        alert(car);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes" selected>Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.car').on('change',function(){
    var car=$('.car').val();
    alert(car);
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Change function to execute each time the event is triggered.